# Node + Mailchimp NPM: How to add a subscriber to a list and include their first and last name?

Tags: node.js, mailchimp

Mailchimp is almost a perfect company, except their Node API documentation is non-existent. How can I add a subscriber to my new list and include their first name and last name? The code below successfully adds the subscriber, but first and last names are not being added.

```
var MCapi = require('mailchimp-api');
MC        = new MCapi.Mailchimp('***********************-us3');

addUserToMailchimp = function(user, callback) {
  var merge_vars = [
      { EMAIL: user.email }, 
      { LNAME: user.name.substring(user.name.lastIndexOf(" ")+1) },
      { FNAME: user.name.split(' ')[0] }
  ];

  MC.lists.subscribe({id: '1af87a08af', email:{email: user.email}, merge_vars: merge_vars, double_optin: false }, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
  }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
}; // addUserToMailchimp
```

Comment: Is probably a good idea not to share your API keys with people in the Internets.

Answer (score 18):

The supplied merge variables should be passed as a single object, not an array of objects. Please see my example below:

```
var mcReq = {
    id: 'mail-chimp-list-id',
    email: { email: 'subscriber-email-address' },
    merge_vars: {
        EMAIL: 'subscriber-email-address',
        FNAME: 'subscriber-first-name',
        LNAME: 'subscriber-last-name'
    }
};

// submit subscription request to mail chimp
mc.lists.subscribe(mcReq, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

It looks like you supplied your actual mail chimp API key in your question. If so, you should remove it immediately.

Comment: This solution didn't work as mc member `lists` was undefined. The following solution worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54224973/6326807