# How to submit a form (add a subscriber) by mailchimp-api-v3 in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am using [mailchimp-api-v3](https://github.com/thorning/node-mailchimp) to submit a form.

This list only has three fields, which are `FNAME`, `EMAIL`, and `COMPANY`.

```
const Mailchimp = require('mailchimp-api-v3');

const mailchimp = new Mailchimp(myMailchimpAPI);

mailchimp.post(`/lists/${myListId}/members`, {
  FNAME: 'Jack',
  EMAIL: 'jack@example.com',
  COMPANY: 'Apple'
})
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This gives me error:

> [ { field: 'email_address', message: 'This value should not be blank.'
> } ] }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out after reading the Mailchimp [API document](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/).
 I have to add another two fields `email_address` and `status` which are required. Then move the rest of form fields under `merge_fields`.

The correct code is

```
const Mailchimp = require('mailchimp-api-v3');

const mailchimp = new Mailchimp(myMailchimpAPI);

mailchimp.post(`/lists/${myListId}/members`, {
  email_address: 'jack@example.com',
  status: 'subscribed',
  merge_fields: {
    FNAME: 'Jack',
    EMAIL: 'jack@example.com',
    COMPANY: 'Apple'
  }
})
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

It was hard for me to find a simple demo online. Hope this helps for future people.